# Creating basic portfolio website using Locomotive CMS (Ruby on rails, haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, liquid

I've been trying to create a basic portfolio such as this one (www.tommyblue.it) using Locomotive CMS,
I've managed to set up all the needed gems and required programs, mongodb, homebrew etc... 
However due to the extreme difficulty of finding decent haml or Locomotive CMS documentation (for a newbie) online I'm stuck with it. My goal would be to have running app before the end of the month, crazy uh?

Any help is truly appreciated.

Basically this is what I'm stuck with atm:

```
{{ 'js.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'main.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'custom.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.easing.1.3.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.masonry.min.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.prettyPhoto.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.quicksand.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.tweet.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'modernizr.js' | javascript_tag }}
{{ 'style.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'font.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'prettyPhoto.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'reset.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'typography.css' | stylesheet_tag }}





<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
    <head>




        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {{ Design.Diverso }}


    </head>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <body class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <body class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <body class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <body class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->  



    <div class="body-inside">
            <!-- begin header -->
            <header id="header">
                <!-- begin slider -->
                <div id="f_slider">

                    <div class="slider">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h5>HELLO,</h5>
                                    <h2>WELCOME TO <span class="h_black">NONAME</span></h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">   
                                        <h4>                                                                    
                                            Enjoy our company For the design & production of all manner of digital creative.                                            
                                        </h4>                                                   
                                </div>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="row text-center">
                                    <h2>Enjoy <span class="h_black"> our </span>company  </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row one-half text-right">   
                                    <h4>Who we are</h4> 
                                    <div class="content_big">                       
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecadipiscing elit. Duis nec purus tellus, quis pulvinar tortor.
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecadipiscing elit. 
                                    </div>                                                          
                                </div>
                                <div class="row one-half last">
                                    <h4>What we've done</h4>    
                                    <div class="content_big">                       
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecadipiscing elit. Duis nec purus tellus, quis pulvinar tortor.
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consecadipiscing</a> elit. 
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </li>       
                            <li>
                                <div class="row one-half text-right">
                                    <h2> we make  </h2>
                                    <h2> it <span class="h_black">better</span></h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row one-half last">     
                                    <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
                                    <div class="content_big">                       
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar, odio eu consectetur porta, libero orci tempor felis, a adipiscing diam ipsum in enim. Donec hendrerit dictum quam, a tincidunt neque vulputate nec.



                                    <div>                                   
                                        {{ 'html5_logo.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                                        {{ 'css3_logo.png' | theme_image_tag }}                             
                                        {{ 'jquery_logo.png' | theme_image_tag }}                                                                                                                                                                           
                                </div>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </li>                                                   
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end slider -->
                <!-- begin navigation -->

               <nav id="top_menu">
                    <div class="inside">
                        <!-- logo -->
                        <a href="#" class="logo">
                            {{ 'logo.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                        </a>
                        <!-- begin menu -->






                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="works.html">
                                    Works
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="blog.html">
                                    Blog
                                </a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="blog_post.html" title="Single Post">Single Post</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="services.html">
                                    Services
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
                            </li>               
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Features
                                </a>
                                <!-- begin sub menu -->
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="typography.html">
                                            Typography
                                        </a>
                                    </li>   
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="columns.html">
                                            Columns
                                        </a>
                                    </li>   
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="elements.html">
                                            Elements
                                        </a>

                                    </li>   
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="team.html">
                                            Our Team
                                        </a>
                                    </li>   

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contact.html">
                                    Contact
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- end menu -->
                    </div>              
                </nav>
                <!-- end navigation -->
            </header>
            <!-- end header -->
            <!-- begin main -->
            <article id="main">

                <!-- Begin ajax menu -->

                <nav id="to-top-menu">
                    <span></span>
                </nav>

                <!-- end ajax menu -->

                <ul class="fast_link">
                    <li class="">
                        <div class="link_wrap" data-link="works">
                            <div class="link_title">
                                <h2>OUR WORKS</h2>
                                <p>Recent Projects</p>
                            </div>
                            {{ 'a_works.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            {{ 'a_works_hover.png' | theme_image_tag }}>
                            <span class="call_ajax"></span>                                                                                             
                        </div>      
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <div class="link_wrap" data-link="blog">
                            <div class="link_title">
                                <h2>BLOG</h2>
                                <p>From the Blog</p>
                            </div>  
                            {{ 'a_blog.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            {{ 'a_blog_hover.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            <span class="call_ajax"></span>                                                                             
                        </div>                                              
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <div class="link_wrap" data-link="services">
                            <div class="link_title">
                                <h2>SERVICES</h2>
                                <p>What we do</p>
                            </div>
                            {{ 'a_service.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            {{ 'a_service_hover.png' | theme_image_tag }}   
                            <span class="call_ajax"></span>                                                                 
                        </div>              
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <div class="link_wrap" data-link="team">
                            <div class="link_title">
                                <h2>THE TEAM</h2>
                                <p>Meat the team </p>
                            </div>
                            {{ 'a_team.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            {{ 'a_team_hover.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            <span class="call_ajax"></span>                                                                                                             
                        </div>                                          
                    </li>
                    <li class="last">
                        <div class="link_wrap" data-link="contact">
                            <div class="link_title">
                                <h2>CONTACT</h2>
                                <p>Get in touch</p> 
                            </div>
                            {{ 'a_contact.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            {{ 'a_contact_hover.png' | theme_image_tag }}
                            <span class="call_ajax"></span>                                                                                                                 
                        </div>                                          
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <span class="clear"></span>

                <!-- home page title -->
                <nav class="page_title displaynone">

                    <h2>
                        <span class="title">PLACE SELECT A PAGE</span> 
                        <span class="loading_link"></span> 
                    </h2>

                </nav>  

                <!-- callback ajax content -->
                <section id="content">

                </section>
                <span class="clear"></span>

            </article>
            <!-- end main -->
        </div>
        <!-- end body inside -->

        <!-- begin footer -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="inside">            
                <div class="footer-widget">
                    <div class="one-third">                     
                        <h2>Follow Us</h2>
                        <p>
                            Omnes enim peccaverunt et egent gloriam Dei. In principio creavit Deus caelum et terram.
                        </p>

                        <ul class="footer-socials">
                            <li class="rss"><a href="#" title="Rss"></a></li>                           
                            <li class="twitter"><a href="#" title="Twitter"></a></li>
                            <li class="facebook"><a href="#" title="Facebook"></a></li>
                            <li class="dribbble"><a href="#" title="Dribbble"></a></li>                                                     
                            <li class="vimeo"><a href="#" title="Vimeo"></a></li>
                            <li class="skype"><a href="#" title="Skype"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <span class="clear"></span>

                    </div>
                    <div class="one-third">
                        <h2>About Us</h2>
                        <p>{{ 'logo.png' | theme_image_tag }}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar, odio eu consectetur porta, libero orci tempor felis, a adipiscing diam ipsum in enim. Donec hendrerit dictum quam, a tincidunt neque vulputate nec. Proin nec sollicitudin augue. Donec hendrerit</p>                                                                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="one-third last">
                        <h2>Join our newsletter</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pulvinar, odio eu consectetur porta, libero orci tempor felis.</p>                      
                        <form id="form_newslatter">
                            <input type="text" name="newslatter" id="newslatter" placeholder="Email Address..." />
                        </form>                 
                    </div>
                    <span class="clear"></span>
                </div>                                  

                <div class="footer-bottom">
                    <span class="copyright">© 2012 · AGT NoName ( <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://demo.agtheme.com/noname" title="Valid html5"> Valid html5 </a> ) All Rights Reserved</span>
                    <nav id="footer_menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- end footer --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you seen the [HAML documentation](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/REFERENCE.md) on Github?

Comment: @ Pete, yes I saw it, although right now I'm trying to implement this template using liquid template language, I've an html theme that I wanted to adapt for using it inside Locomotive CMS, I tried using haml but it didn't work...

Comment: Please see above for the template implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use twitter bootstrap as your theme for it includes a pretty nice and lighweight carousel and create a Photos model with a file and description fields then in your page implement somthing like this in locomotive:

```
{% for photo in contents.photos %}
        <li>
          <a href='{{ photo.fichier.url | resize: '800x600' }}' title="{{ photo.legende }}">{{ photo.fichier.url | image_tag  }}</a>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is an example, don't just copy and paste since I'm using this with fundation as a theme and lightbox for photos.
Let me know if you need further explanation (I don't have time right now).

Comment: Thanks Manuite I actually tried the twitter bootstrap theme although I have hard times to figure out how to edit it, secondly I'd love to use the above mentioned layout, I'm still struggling to integrate it into Locomotive. Basically I'd need to blend the liquid templating language into my html layout. 
Fact is I've found too little documentation on liquid templating laguage online, at least not enough for me, so I'm stuck in the process of integration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this stuff carefully 
 http://doc.locomotivecms.com/installation/getting_started

Also I have the clue you are mixing 2 things at this very moment:

- CMS is explained as Content Management System therefor you will be able to Manage your Content with this System ;)
- Ruby on rails is the main web development tool you use to build the housing of your website in  the so called server side and client side.

So try to make a website in Ruby on Rails first. then add your CMS system to it and that should do it.

Comment: :) Locomotive CMS is ready full featured content management system written in ruby in rails am just trying to develop my website with it www.locomotive.com btw I'm perfectly aware of what ruby on rails is (just don't have that much experience) and also what a C.M.S. does, thanks for the input ;) however this doesn't really answer my question though.

Comment: Well than right now I must thank you for your info about the possibilities within locomotive awesome!